# Bridge Edge Loops creates a Sharp Face

Tags: modeling, faces, edges

I am trying to follow the [Teacup tutorial by Blender Guru](https://youtu.be/SBtDix7xGOg?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&t=364). I have made my cup and it's handle and I am trying to bridge the edge loops to merge the other part of the handle back into the cup. However a new face gets generated, which looks like a sharp plane. I have tried deleting the face, and changing the sizes of the edge loops, but I am unable to get a clean handle merger. Adding a face by selecting 2 vertices on each side leads to similar problems.

[image: Image of the Cup]
[image: The Image of the unintentional face]

[image]

Comment: First make sure you have no duplicate vertices -Select your whole mesh in edit mode, then press M and select "by distance". Then recalculate your normals - also with the whole mesh selected in edit mode, select `mesh > normals > recalculate outside` from the menu at the top of the viewport.

Comment: if Christopher's answer does not help, please provide blend file, then we can give you a step by step explanation with your data.

Comment: I tried doing that, but all the cyclic edge loops were lost and I couldn't connect the two parts finally. I have undone the recalculating outside step and uploaded the blend file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- While in edit mode, select all (<kbd>A</kbd>), then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals.

Tested on your blend file, can confirm that this will fix your problem.

This is a very, very frequent problem with new modelers like myself. **When in doubt, fix your normals!**

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the edge loop of the handle a face. In the tutorial, he grabs the two faces and then bridges the edge loops. Your model does not have a face at the end of the teacup handle.

You can fix this by selecting the four edges at the end of the handle (`alt-click` to select the loop), and press `F` to create a face.

Then, go into face select mode and select the two faces you want to bridge. Then press `CTRL + E` and select "Bridge Edge Loop".

Comment: Don't think this is it. My model has a face, I think an extra face. I deleted and started over, never knowing what it was. But I think I had one too many faces there somewhere, even though I tried deleting.